# Kotlin Composable detectDragGestures Output On Drop Position?

Tags: drag-and-drop, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I have a Kotlin jetpack composable box item that I set to be able to click and drag. It outputs all the real time coordinates of the box, but is there a way to output only the last value the moment I lift my fingers and dropping the box?

```
@Composable
fun createDragImage(){
    MaterialTheme{
        val count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
        val context = LocalContext.current

        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(20.dp)
                .border(border = BorderStroke(width = 1.dp, color = Color.Red)),
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically,

        ) {

            Box() {
                var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
                var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

                Box(
                    Modifier
                        .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                        .background(Color.Transparent)
                        .size(150.dp)
                        .border(BorderStroke(4.dp, SolidColor(Color.Red)))
                        .pointerInput(Unit) {
                            detectDragGestures { change, dragAmount ->
                                change.consumeAllChanges()
                                
                                offsetX = box1.toFloat() 
                                offsetY += dragAmount.y

                            }
                        }
                )
                
            }
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `onDragEnd` parameter.
Something like:

```
        var offsetX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetDraggingX by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }
        var offsetDraggingY by remember { mutableStateOf(0f) }

        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset { IntOffset(offsetX.roundToInt(), offsetY.roundToInt()) }
                .pointerInput(Unit) {
                    detectDragGestures(
                        onDragEnd = {
                            offsetX =  offsetDraggingX
                            offsetY =  offsetDraggingY
                        }
                    ) { change, dragAmount ->
                        //change.consumeAllChanges()

                        offsetDraggingX += dragAmount.x
                        offsetDraggingY += dragAmount.y

                    }
                }

        )
```

Comment: This worked exactly how it should except it now exponentially slows down the program when it's processing the box animation. Seems the onDragEnd method is extremely taxing when inside detectDragGestures. Dragging the box and also any println() outputs are very slow.